# install omniorb python in a virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip, corba

I am trying to install [omniorb](http://omniorb.sourceforge.net/) in a virtualenv for python.

Doing this using the included configure script with omniorb seems rather difficult.

Does anyone know about a pip, setup.py or easy_install script for omniorb?

Comment: What platform are you doing this on? Linux, Windows, or ...?

Comment: My main environment is ubuntu 11.04 64 bit, but I was hoping for something platform-independent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Out of curiosity I just tried this on Ubuntu 10.04. I don't have a pip or setup.py solution for you, but it isn't too hard.

I think the secret is to set the PYTHON variable to configure to point to the python executable in your virtualenv. I built omniORB and omniORBPy from source and installed them to a directory under my virtualenv (by specifying the `--prefix` option to configure).

You then have to put the `site-packages` directory that gets created under the omniORB install directory on your `PYTHONPATH`. I chose to do this by creating a `omniorb.pth` file in my virtualenv's `site-packages` folder (more on this below).

Here is the shell history of what I did. I am working out of a directory `/home/brian/coding/python/virtualenvs`. You'll have to mentally adjust paths, etc. for your environment.

```
 virtualenv omniORB
 cd omniORB/
 . bin/activate
 cp /home/brian/Downloads/omni* .
 tar xvfj omniORB-4.1.6.tar.bz2 
 tar xvfj omniORBpy-3.6.tar.bz2 
 mkdir omniORB_install
 cd omniORB-4.1.6/
 mkdir build
 cd build
 ../configure --prefix=/home/brian/coding/python/virtualenvs/omniORB/omniORB_install/ PYTHON=/home/brian/coding/python/virtualenvs/omniORB/bin/python 
 make
 make install
 cd ../../omniORBpy-3.6/
 mkdir build
 cd build
 ../configure --prefix=/home/brian/coding/python/virtualenvs/omniORB/omniORB_install/ PYTHON=/home/brian/coding/python/virtualenvs/omniORB/bin/python --with-omniorb=/home/brian/coding/python/virtualenvs/omniORB/omniORB_install/
 make
 make install
```

Now here is that `omniorb.pth` file I mentioned earlier. Change directory to the top of your virtualenv. Create `omniorb.pth` such that it looks and is located like this:

```
$ cat lib/python2.6/site-packages/omniorb.pth 
/home/brian/coding/python/virtualenvs/omniORB/omniORB_install/lib/python2.6/site-packages
```

Now, inside my activated virtualenv:

```
$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import CORBA
>>> CORBA.__file__
'/home/brian/coding/python/virtualenvs/omniORB/omniORB_install/lib/python2.6/site-packages/omniORB/CORBA.pyc'
>>>
```

Comment: This works like a charm. Unless something spectacular happens, I will accept this answer soon.

Comment: I have just tried this and it worked for me but only when I am in `lib` dir with e.g. in your example it would be `/home/brian/coding/python/virtualenvs/omniORB/omniORB_install/`. In other directories in your example I get: `... import _omnipy
ImportError: libomniORB4.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. So I needed to add some hacks in `activate` script to change (and restore) `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: @Patryk if it only works when you are in the `lib` directory it sounds like your virtualenv isn't active and it is finding the files it needs in the current directory.

Comment: @BrianNeal It is active when I try to `python -c "import CORBA"`